# Error when importing SQL Dump from an equal source

Tags: mysql, database

I need to sync the database of a live server to our development system, so I did create a dump with `mysqldump`, zipped it, piped it to the other server, unzipped it and wanted to import said dump. Quite the no-brainer, right?

`mysql -uroot -pPASS DBNAME < dump.sql`

This is where the error occurs.

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 270: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''{\n \"parsed_parameters\":91,\n \"max_result\":[\n  {\"time\":5076987.68,\"outp' at line 1

Edit: This does also happen if I use the MySQL CL with `source`.

This is odd, as every technical aspect of the live system is equal to the dev system, the only difference is the backend and the data in the database.

So I am wondering why I can't insert this dump despite having a comparable database with the same schema as the source.

Edit: Just for testing I created an empty database and got the same error.

*But the thing I don't get is, that the process successfully imported exactly 500 rows with similar values. Maybe there is something with this 500 rows threshold?*

Answer (score 0):

You need to login first using below cmd

```
mysql -u <your-username> -p
```

After click enter it will asking for password please enter it, then using below you can import dump in specific schema.

```
use <schema-name>;
source database/filepath/dump.sql;
```

If you have not created schema then create it using below cmd first after login.

```
create schema your_schema_name;
```

Comment: Please share more details - why should importing a dump not work using the usual way, but only using `source`?

Comment: @NicoHaase second this, as afaik `source`  should only be used when handling small sql files

Comment: @pguetschow I have used this commands for about 5GB dump file. I am not sure for more than that.

Comment: But I think that's a thing of personal preference. The error remains the same, I updated the Question with more information